# Make a new array with one element of a multidimenional array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object in a JavaScript function:

```
[{"PMID":31206477,"MemberID":1287,"recID":6352},
{"PMID":31202264,"MemberID":1245,"recID":5974},
{"PMID":31201299,"MemberID":1184,"recID":3012},
{"PMID":31196160,"MemberID":1241,"recID":3833}]
```

That is saved to an Multi-dimensional Array

Is there a better way that I can make a make a new Array with only the PMID element without looping and building it.  I know that this question is close to a duplicate but I'm not interested in a merge or a concat.  Currently I'm doing

```
      var newArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.pmidList.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(this.pmidList[i]["PMID"]);
      }
```

This question maybe a duplicate but if the average person can't find it based upon the title then it should not be considered a duplicate.  The solution is the same but the question titles are much different.

Comment: "without looping it" is impossible, without using `for` is probably what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Array.map` function.

```
const input = [{"PMID":31206477,"MemberID":1287,"recID":6352},
  {"PMID":31202264,"MemberID":1245,"recID":5974},
  {"PMID":31201299,"MemberID":1184,"recID":3012},
  {"PMID":31196160,"MemberID":1241,"recID":3833}];

const output = input.map(item => item.PMID);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks for the answer-  I was sure this was a duplicate question but I could never find it.  Hopefully my title will make it a bit easier to find.